# Fade in/out on scroll divs are invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, what I want to happen is a class of divs to fade in/out on scroll. It seems to work perfectly on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/1/) page.

The only change I made to the code was adding this plug-in, but it still doesn't seem to work, and the posts are just invisible:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Am I perhaps using the wrong plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you include the JavasScript?

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {
    function fade() {
        $('.fade').each(function() {
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
            
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
            if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
                if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
            } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
                if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
            }
        });
    }
    fade(); //Fade in completely visible elements during page-load
    $(window).scroll(function() {fade();}); //Fade in elements during scroll
});
```

2. Did you call the script after jQuery loaded?
3. Did you include the CSS?

```css
.fade {
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

3. Did you include the HTML?

```html
<div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 01</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 02</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 03</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 04</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 05</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 06</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 07</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 08</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 09</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 10</div>
</div>
```

4. Did you make it HTML5?

Here is the complete code to make it work.

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {
    function fade() {
        $('.fade').each(function() {
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
            
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
            if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
                if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
            } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
                if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
            }
        });
    }
    fade(); //Fade in completely visible elements during page-load
    $(window).scroll(function() {fade();}); //Fade in elements during scroll
});
```

```css
.fade {
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 01</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 02</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 03</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 04</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 05</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 06</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 07</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 08</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 09</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery sourcefile in head portion, You have to load jquery file first.

```
<head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script></head>
```

You have to load jquery before running the snippet of code

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
    function fade() {
        $('.fade').each(function() {
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
            if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
                if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
            } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
                if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
            }
        });
    }
    fade(); //Fade in completely visible elements during page-load
    $(window).scroll(function() {fade();}); //Fade in elements during scroll
});
```

Comment: Missing jQuery would throw an error, she said she gets no errors.